# How to fix Login/Register Issue facebook E/BufferQueueProducer: [FacebookActivity[5278]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)

Tags: java, android, facebook-login

I am having trouble with connecting to facebook login/register in my android studio project I have configured all the things provided from facebook,opening up the logcat I get this kind of error when trying to register/Sign in to the app (using Facebook Login and Register system from browser works when facebook is not installed but when trying to login/register from the app doesn't work and throws the logcat bellow) any help would be great as I am stuck with this for 2 days.

2019-08-31 15:20:21.315 3318-3393/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.prototype.mk/com.facebook.FacebookActivity[5278]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-08-31 15:20:21.503 3723-3818/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{8cb214b u0 com.prototype.mk/com.facebook.FacebookActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:870 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:851 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5414 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.onAnimationFinished:2394 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2

Comment: Check the internet connection on the device and try again.

Comment: Adding user_friends to the logInWithReadPermissions fixed this issue for me